# SQL Fill Constants Incase there is no match in joining two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Say I have a table:

```
+--------+-----------+----------+
|style_id|SegmentName|StyleViews|
+--------+-----------+----------+
|1       |Z          |1         |
|1       |X          |2         |
|2       |Z          |1         |
|1       |Y          |2         |
|3       |Y          |1         |
|3       |X          |1         |
+--------+-----------+----------+
```

Lets call it table1

and another table:

```
+-----------+
|allsegments|
+-----------+
|X          |
|Y          |
|Z          |
+-----------+
```

Lets call it table2

How do I reach at an output something like this:

```
+--------+-----------+----------+
|style_id|SegmentName|StyleViews|
+--------+-----------+----------+
|1       |X          |2         |
|1       |Y          |2         |
|1       |Z          |1         |
|2       |X          |0         |
|2       |Y          |0         |
|2       |Z          |1         |
|3       |X          |1         |
|3       |Y          |1         |
|3       |Z          |0         |
+--------+-----------+----------+
```

Essentially, if there is no match when table1 is joined with table2, it mush add 0s in place.

Seems like a pretty simple problem, however I have tried all sorts of joins like full_outer, left_outer, right_outer however, I am not able to accomplish what I want. Any help on this regard will be appreciated.

I am trying to do this in spark sql, however I think this problem is a general sql problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and a `left join` to bring in the values:

```
select s.style_id, se.segmentname, coalesce(styleviews, 0) as styleviews
from (select distinct style_id from table1) s cross join
     allsegments se left join
     table1 t
     on t.style_id = s.style_id and
        t.segmentname = se.segmentname;
```

Comment: Thanks ... exactly what I was looking for :)